# curl fetching content of redirected webpage

Tags: php, redirect, curl, authentication

I try to login in a site which has a combined login.

The redirect to this site works fine and the redirect back as well ... but only if I stop the PHP programm with `die()`. Unfortunately it is not stored in $return, which I would need to proceed.

Any ideas, what I am doing wrong? Much appreciated!

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,    FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,    FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,    TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,              TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,    TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR,         TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,               URI_LOGIN);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

// PREPARING THE LOGIN
$referer = URI_LOGIN . '?ReturnUrl=' . urlencode('/returnUrl/');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,         $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,     $referer);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,   COOKIE);

$post = ...;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  http_build_query($post) );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,   '...');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

// LOGIN 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, COMBINED_LOGIN);

$post = ...;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post) );

$return = curl_exec($ch);

// ...
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with javascript. It stucked on an 'in-between'-page and I had to make another curl request to get to the right page.

Now it is working fine!